# Set NSMenu as NSWindow's main menu from the NIB?

Tags: cocoa, nib, nsmenu

I've got two menus in my app, one will be attached to NSStatusBar and another will be app's main menu.

Is there a way to set one of the NSMenu's as the main one right from the Nib?  I'm looking at another project's nib and I see the menu actually defined in the nib, while in my nib it's not showing up correctly.

Right now my app has no menu at all.

This is what my nib looks like:

[image: My Nib]

How I want it to look like:

[image: How I want it to show up]

Comment: Um, your second screen shot is showing the main menu defined in the nib. Isn't this exactly what you want? Just modify the existing menu bar in the nib.

Comment: @RobKeniger: The question says that the screenshot showing “how I want it to look like” is of “another project's nib”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In xibs, at least in Xcode 4, the main menu is no longer an outlet of the application but rather a nature that a top-level menu object either has or doesn't have. The main menu in a main menu nib created by Xcode has that nature; a menu you create yourself does not.

As of Xcode 4.2.1, there is no way to  create a menu from scratch in an existing nib and appoint it as the main menu. You must create a nib with the main menu already in it using the appropriate file template.

Comment: Sounds like my experience.  I went ahead and created a new project and it's there now.  Thanks for your help.